# How to add the timezone offset to a timestamp?

Tags: oracle, timezone-offset

How can I add the time zone offset in the third query?

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
# +01:00

SELECT TZ_OFFSET(SESSIONTIMEZONE) FROM DUAL;
# +01:00

SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('19700101000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')+NUMTODSINTERVAL(86400,'SECOND'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
# 1970-01-02 00:00:00
```

The desired result would be

```
# 1970-01-02 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FROM_TZ` to convert your `TIMESTAMP` to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` on the `UTC` time zone and then use `AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE` to convert it to your local time and then convert it back to a string:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='Europe/Paris';
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
          FROM_TZ(
            TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '86400' SECOND,
            'UTC'
          ) AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE,
          'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS ts
FROM   DUAL
```

or, more simply:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
          (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
          AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE,
          'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS ts
FROM   DUAL
```

| TS |
| --- |
| 1970-01-02 01:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qT05lIol)

Comment: I had to keep the `NUMTODSINTERVAL(86400,'SECOND')` part because the seconds are provided as integers.

Comment: @sid_com The other alternative is `86400 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not take summer/winter time into account.

Comment: @sid_com That is because your session time zone is `+01:00` (which does not have DST) and not `Europe/Paris` (which would have DST). Fix your time zone and you should see that it works. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jvc4gcmO) (Also, your question makes no mention of DST.)